# what is difference between region around a charge and region out of it?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, potential-energy, voltage

Basically I want to know what makes  a region around a charge particle so affective that another charge will have energy when brought in this region or it will experience a force when enters into this region

Comment: If you are asking why charge repel/attract other charges, the answer is that no one knows. The exact same question can be asked about gravity.

Comment: @Steeven That is not true. The origin and nature of forces (for both electromagnetic theory and gravity) can be straightforwardly derived from basic quantum field theory (e.g. see Zee's book on QFT for an exposition).

Answer (score 0):

A Charge experiences a force when brought close to another charge because the charges have *a field of force* which is the **electric field** around them. For why these fields exist, no one really knows exactly why as some explanations include quantum field theory as that's how our universe works. For point charges the force between them is given by Coulomb's law: 
$$F=\frac{Q_1Q_2}{4\pi\epsilon_0r^2}$$

Where $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ are the charges and $r$ is the distance between charges, while the other terms are constants.

The charges get *electric potential* energy when one is moved closer to another because work/energy is required/found when a force( here the electric force) acts on a charge through a distance( work done = force x distance moved in direction of force) , hence these charges have an electric potential energy in an electric field formed from them.